# Intent vs Content Provider in android

Tags: android

I am new in android app development and while studying about the basic android components I got confused between intents and content provider as both are being used to send data from one application/component to another application/component . In case of intents we can send data using bundle or extras so why do we use content providers. Can someone please explain me this with a example . 
 Also can we access database in android only using content provider and is this the sole reason why we use content providers ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> both are being used to send data from one application/component to another application/component

Not really.

There are four components in Android:

- `Activity`
- `Service`
- `BroadcastReceiver`
- `ContentProvider`

An `Intent` is none of those. An `Intent` is *involved* when we start an activity, start or bind to a service, or send a broadcast. However, comparing an `Intent` to a `ContentProvider` is akin to comparing a shovel with a boot, arguing that both can be used to carry dirt. While true, usually a boot is *involved* in carrying dirt, but the actual means of carrying dirt is handled by something else, such as a wheelbarrow.

> In case of intents we can send data using bundle or extras so why do we use content providers.

We often use different tools for different circumstances. For example, you will find it rather difficult to carry water in a fishing net.

Each of the four components has a different role, particularly in relationship to inter-process communication (IPC):

- An `Activity` drives the bulk of our user interface, including starting up activities from other apps (or having one of our activities be started by other apps)
- A `Service` exists for longer-running operations that are logically decoupled from the user interface, including working with services that are implemented by other apps (or having other apps work with services that you publish)
- A `BroadcastReceiver` is a publish/subscribe messaging system, to allow you to send messages to arbitrary subscribers, or to subscribe to messages from arbitrary senders, across process boundaries
- A `ContentProvider` is for bulk data transfer, whether in the form of a database-style structure (rows and columns) or in the form of a stream, particularly for working with other apps

> Also can we access database in android only using content provider

No. After all, if that were true, it would be impossible to access a database. A `ContentProvider` does not appear by magic. It has to be written by a programmer. If a `ContentProvider` could only access a database by means of a `ContentProvider`, we would have a problem.

> is this the sole reason why we use content providers ?

No. In addition to offering a database-style API, a `ContentProvider` can also publish a stream. This is important for getting arbitrary data between apps, such as an email client making a PDF attachment available to a PDF viewer.

Comment: Perfect explanation that too line by line. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Need a bit advice. What should I study first , content providers or android database ?

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal: Neither. Or, more accurately, come up with a real problem, then learn what you need to solve the problem. If, for example, your problem involves getting at contact data, you need to learn how to work with a `ContentProvider`, because that is how Android makes contact data available to you.

Comment: Ohh , I think I was going bit wrong. What I am doing is that I am first trying to learn about basic android components from developer.google api guides(which I feel gets a tough job for a beginner at times) and then I am planning to impliment all that into an android application which have in mind. So basically there are two ways- 1. Learn all basic components first them implement them 2. Learn only those things that you need currently . –    so which approach should I follow ?

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal: I cannot answer that, as I do not know how best you like to learn.

Comment: Still if you can give me a advice or tell me the recommended way ?

Comment: @CommonsWare your example with email client and PDF viewer - I suppose it is possible to use Implicit Intent for this reason but not only Content Provider approach

Comment: @Bohdan: This answer is over 5 years old. In the intervening time, using a `ContentProvider` to serve a stream of content has gotten even more important, given scoped storage and related filesystem restrictions. While using a `content` `Uri` with an implicit `Intent` is a common pattern, it certainly is not the only one.

Answer (score 2):

Intents are a messaging architecture for sending /receiving transactional commands and data.  Content providers are an abstract interface to stored data for create,update, delete and sync operations.

Comment: and what about database ?

Comment: A database, such as android's built in sqllite database, is one type of storage mechanism for the data.  A content provider can use a database, file store or other storage mechanism.  The content provider interface allows you to abstract that storage mechanism from the rest of your application or other applications.