# Intent and content provider

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am new in android app development and while studying about the basic android components I got confused between intents and content provider as both are being used to send data from one application/component to another application/component . 
i just want to know, can Intent provide data to content Provider? why or why not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent vs Content Provider in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897520/intent-vs-content-provider-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

They are different things.

Basically, Content providers can help an application manage access to data stored by itself, stored by other apps, and provide a way to share data with other apps.  Navigate this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers to get an idea about the content provider

Basically, An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed. you can get idea about intent by navigating https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

you can get all other details about compare by nevigating this [Intent vs Content Provider in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897520/intent-vs-content-provider-in-android)